# GAE cloud endpoints - Fail to load endpoint class on Appengine log

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When I try the list API I've in the log:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiConfigLoader loadConfiguration: Fail to load endpoint class class com.twitter.TweetEndpoint with ApiConfigSource class com.google.api.server.spi.config.datastore.ApiConfigDatastoreReader
```

I've a Tweet entity and a TweetEndpoint class generated by Eclipse.

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solution or reason for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is related to this Issue:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9824